# VBA filtering dates

Tags: vba, excel

This is my function, the code stops on the line "If pitem.visible=True" on the first iteration (line 17). While the code is running, I always have visible items int the field.
The code is not even setting any property to visible and it's working very well if I filter anything other than a date.

```
Function tableau()

    Dim fld As PivotField
    Dim pitem As PivotItem
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim a As String
    Dim pvt As String

pvt = "PivotTable"
Sheets("Données").ListObjects("table1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Sheets("PivotTableSheet").Activate
Sheets("PivotTableSheet").PivotTables(pvt).ManualUpdate = True
Sheets("PivotTableSheet").PivotTables(pvt).PivotFields("Date").EnableMultiplePageItems = True


For Each fld In Sheets("PivotTableSheet").PivotTables(pvt).PivotFields
        If fld.Orientation <> xlHidden And (fld.Orientation = xlPageField) Then        'loop through filtered pivot fields
            i = 1
            For Each pitem In fld.PivotItems                                           'loop through visible items in filtered pivot fields
                If pitem.Visible = True Then
                    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To i) As Variant
                    arr(i) = pitem
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next pitem
            Sheets("Données").ListObjects("table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=TRVFILTRE(fld.Name), Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If

    Next fld
Sheets("PivotTableSheet").PivotTables(pvt).ManualUpdate = False

End Function
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating over PivotItems, there's a couple of bottlenecks and gotchas that you want to avoid. See my post at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ for more on this.

Among other things, you want to set the PivotTable's ManualUpdate property to TRUE while you do the iteration and then back to FALSE when you're done. Otherwise Excel will try to update the PivotTable each time you change the visibility of a PivotItem. And you also want to ensure that at least one item remains visible at all times. I use something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPivot()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim i As Long
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim vItems As Variant

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1") '<= Change to match your PivotTable
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("CountryName") '<= Change to match your PivotField

vItems = Array("FRANCE", "BELGIUM", "LUXEMBOURG") '<= Change to match the list of items you want to remain visible

pt.ManualUpdate = True 'Stops PivotTable from refreshing after each PivotItem is changed

With pf

    'At least one item must remain visible in the PivotTable at all times, so make the first
    'item visible, and at the end of the routine, check if it actually  *should* be visible        
    .PivotItems(1).Visible = True

    'Hide any other items that aren't already hidden.
    'Note that it is far quicker to check the status than to change it.
    ' So only hide each item if it isn't already hidden
    For i = 2 To .PivotItems.Count
        If .PivotItems(i).Visible Then .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i

    'Make the PivotItems of interest visible
    On Error Resume Next 'In case one of the items isn't found
    For Each vItem In vItems
        .PivotItems(vItem).Visible = True
    Next vItem
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Hide the first PivotItem, unless it is one of the countries of interest
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(UCase(Join(vItems, "|")), UCase(.PivotItems(1))) = 0 Then .PivotItems(1).Visible = False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        .ClearAllFilters
        MsgBox Title:="No Items Found", Prompt:="None of the desired items was found in the Pivot, so I have cleared the filter"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End With

pt.ManualUpdate = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still have the same issue after enabling and disabling manual update. I also have always a visible item in the table so this should not be a problem.

Comment: What line of code does the error appear on? And what is the exact wording of the error? Can you fire up the macro recorder, filter a few dates in or out, and post the resulting code in your answer?

Comment: In terms of always having a visible item, that must be *at all times while the code is running*, not just after it has finished. So you pretty much can't guarantee that at some stage the code will hide all items that were previously visible mid loop, before it has got to the part where you want to unhide other items that were previously hidden. And if/when that happens, your code will throw an error.

Comment: That didn't post...probably because of length. Better to add it to your original question

Comment: I just edited my question, with the new function, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate through PivotItems if all you want to do is make each PivotItem visible. Instead, just use the .ClearAllFilters method.

Something like:

```
  With Sheets("PivotTableSheet").PivotTable("PivotTable").PivotFields("Date")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .CurrentPage = "(All)"
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm trying to set some of the pivot item property to visible (with a condition). I still have the same error.

Comment: Okay. Can you please amend your question to include this requirement.

Comment: Check out my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442383/select-all-pivot-items-that-match-list-of-items-in-another-excel-sheet/51449464#51449464